# LOAD error mismatched input '-' expecting RIGHT_PAREN, column with hyphen

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, ambari

**My code:**

> book = LOAD '/user/samanthafox/books.csv' USING PigStorage (',') AS (ISBN:chararray, Book-Title:chararray,Book-Author:chararray,Year-Of-Publication:chararray,Publisher:chararray);
> dump book ;

**Error code:**

> org.apache.pig.PigServer - exception during parsing: Error during parsing. <file script.pig, line 1, column 89> mismatched input '-' expecting RIGHT_PAREN

Answer (score 2):

You can't have hyphens in column names. For best practice I'd advise only using lower-case letters and underscores - you're unlikely to encounter problems in any kind of data store if you do this.

```
book = LOAD '/user/samanthafox/books.csv' USING PigStorage (',') AS
(isbn: chararray, book_title: chararray, book_author: chararray, year_of_publication: chararray, publisher: chararray);
dump book;
```